# jquery turn querystring into object

Tags: jquery

```
var obj = {
    'key': 'value',
    'cheese':'bacon',
    '&':'>'
};    
var params = $.param(obj)

console.log(params); // key=value&cheese=bacon&%26=%3E
```

how do I turn `params` back into an object? (exactly what it was before)

Comment: all of those methods help you find a single param in the string. I want a single object with keys and values of the querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) has a [**deparam**](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) function: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/blob/master/jquery.ba-bbq.js line 466

Comment: sweet this ended up being the safest method. here is the snippet I took from BBQ: https://gist.github.com/1163405

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this.  I'm not aware of a jQuery built-in for this.

```
function getUrlVars() {
    if (!window.location.search) {
        return({});   // return empty object
    }
    var parms = {};
    var temp;
    var items = window.location.search.slice(1).split("&");   // remove leading ? and split
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        temp = items[i].split("=");
        if (temp[0]) {
            if (temp.length < 2) {
                temp.push("");
            }
            parms[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);        
        }
    }
    return(parms);
}
```