# jQuery - How to remove duplicate parameter on string? (not array)

Tags: jquery, variables, parameters, compare, duplicates

I have 2 variable with value and character '&' to determinate parameter (like URL parameter).

**Note**: This is not a parameter from URL and not is a Array!

```
variable1 = value1=bla&value2=ble&page=test&value4=blo&test=blu&car=red
variable2 = page=index&car=blue&other=yellow
```

I need compare 2 variables and eliminate duplicate parameters, and if have same parameter on variable1 and variable2, i need exclude parameter from variable1 and use parameter from variable2.

Like this:

```
value1=bla&value2=ble&page=index&value4=blo&test=blu&car=blue&other=yellow
```

How to get this?

Comment: Convert the strings to objects, merge them, and convert the result back to a string.

Comment: You can give me a example?

Comment: Convert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7128954/218196, merge: http://stackoverflow.com/q/171251/218196, serialize: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1714786/218196

Comment: I am not an experienced programmer, it did not help much.

Answer (score 2):

I've build this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aubricus/NEXLd/) to help you out. I've attempted to keep it as vanilla as possible and left comments.

Quickly – This simply parses the parameter string and replaces duplicate parameter **names** with the last **value** found. I couldn't tell exactly what you needed from your question; but maybe this will help get you going.

Here's the JSFiddle code for reference:

```
/**
 * Open up the console to see what's going on
 */

function parse(str) {
    // parse will split the string along the &
    // and loop over the result

    var keyValues, i, len, el, 
        parts, key, value, result;

    result    = {};
    sepToken  = '&';
    keyValues = str.split('&');

    i   = 0;
    len = keyValues.length;

    for(i; i<len; i++) {
        el    = keyValues[i];
        parts = el.split('=');
        key   = parts[0];
        value = parts[1];

        // this will replace any duplicate param 
        // with the last value found
        result[key] = value;
    }

    return result;
}

function serialize(data) {
    // serialize simply loops over the data and constructs a new string

    var prop, result, value;

    result = [];

    for(prop in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            value = data[prop];

            // push each seriialized key value into an array
            result.push(prop + '=' + value);
        }
    }

    // return the resulting array joined on &
    return result.join("&");
}

function run() {
    // run this example

    var paramStr, data, result; 

    // paramStr has a duplicate param, value1
    paramStr = 'value1=bla&value1=foop&value2=ble&page=test&value4=blo&test=blu&car=red';
    data     = parse(paramStr);
    result   = serialize(data);

    return result;

}

console.log(run());
```